# implication introduction in logic

Tags: logic

I read that implication like $a\Rightarrow b$ can be proof using the following steps:

1. suppose $a$ true.
2. Then deduce $b$ from $a$.
3. Then you can conclude that $a\Rightarrow b$ is true.

Actually my real problem is to understand why step 1 and 2 are sufficient to prove that $a\Rightarrow b$ is true. I mean, how can you prove the truth table of $a\Rightarrow b$ just using 1 and 2?

I know that implication $a\Rightarrow b$ is actually defined as "not($a$) or $b$". How can steps 1 and 2 can prove that a and b are related like "not($a$) or $b$" ?

Comment: You do not "prove the truth table of $a \to b$"; you already have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of implication introduction ($\mathord{\to{}}I$) do **not** alone exhaust the classical meaning of implication as given by the truth tables. You still need a strictly classical principle like the classical rule of *reductio ad absurdum* or double negation elimination or the principle of excluded middle or Peirce's law or DeMorgan's law (as in the answer from @Bram28) or something of the kind (I am here supposing that you are not allowed to assume classical logic at the outset, otherwise the question does not really make sense, since the classical meaning of implication and, therefore, the truth tables for implication, are embedded as background assumptions).

More precisely, from $a\to{b}$ you can prove $\lnot(a\wedge{\lnot{b}})$ in a logic where implication is solely determined by $\mathord{\to{}}I$ (like intuitionistic or minimal logic), but not the other way around. The formulas $a\to{b}$, $\lnot(a\wedge{\lnot{b}})$ and $\lnot{a}\vee{b}$ are only equivalent *classically*. So, if you begin only with $\mathord{\to{}}I$, you cannot show the validity of the full classical truth table for implication. On the other hand, if you begin with the truth table for implication, you can show the validity of $\mathord{\to{}}I$, and more. Now, if $b$ is shown to follow *classically* (in a strict sense) from $a$, then, indeed, you can show that the truth table for implication holds between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: ok so here's how i saw it : if you suppose A true, and deduce B from A. It means that A^not(B) cannot be true. Therefore, since there's only two truth values, A^not(B) is obviously false cause it can only be false if it is not true. so not(A^not(B)) is true, so by the Morgan Law : (not(A) or B) is true which is equivalent to (A=>B) is true. Am i right ?

Comment: @toto I say you're right ... because that's exactly what I said in my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

What you show by steps 1 and 2 is that it is impossible for $a$ to be true and $b$ to be false. So, you could say that what you show is $\neg (a \land \neg b)$, which by DeMorgan is equivalent to $\neg a \lor b$

Comment: Ok, but what is the logical argument which makes you able to say "it is impossible to have (a and not(b)) so you can conclude not(a and not(b))." I mean, which logical argument allows you to negate (a and not(b)) ?

Comment: @toto because of the deduction of $b$ from $a$ and whatever other assumptions hold at that time. Thta's what logical validity and consequence means: it is impossible for the assumptions to be true and the inferred statement to be false.

Comment: @toto Assume $a\to{b}$. Now, from $a\wedge{\lnot{b}}$, we get $a$ which, together with $a\to{b}$, gives us $b$. But, from $a\wedge{\lnot{b}}$, we can also get $\lnot{b}$ which, together with the $b$ obtained earlier, gives us a contradiction. Therefore, we cannot have $a\wedge{\lnot{b}}$ in the presence of $a\to{b}$, that is, from $a\to{b}$ we get $\lnot{(a\wedge{\lnot{b}})}$.

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira ok, i get your proof. But since you used reductio ad absurdum to conclude. Do i need to deduce that supposing a and deduce b to conclude a->b don't work in intuitionnistic logic ? How intuitionnist proove implication then ?

Comment: @toto The deduction of $\lnot{(a\wedge{\lnot{b}})}$ from $a\to{b}$ works not only in intuitionistic logic but even in minimal logic. The "reduction ad absurdum" used here is intuitionistically correct since it is used to obtain a negative formula. The strictly classical "reductio ad absurdum" goes from a negative assumption to a positive conclusion, discharging the negative assumption on the way, which is not intuitionistically acceptable. People usually call "reduction ad absurdum" only the strictly classical principle.

Comment: @toto Intuitionistically, the way to prove a negative formula $\lnot{A}$ is to derive a contradiction from $A$. This is why it is common in intuitionistic logic to abbreviate negation as $\lnot{A}\equiv{A\to{\bot}}$, where $\bot$ stands for contradiction, or absurdity.

Comment: OK great I didn't knew that difference amang reduction ad absurdum and negation. Thanks a lot.